# How to find who send the sigterm signal to my process or my process group?

Tags: c, linux, unix

We have a daemon server program which forks one child. When the child exits, Parent is receiving `SIGTERM` signal. So, we want to know

1) Who sent this `SIGTERM`?

2) Whether the `SIGTERM` is only for parent or its group?

3) What are the possible ways `SIGTERM` can be generated under this scenario?

4) Is it possible to mask this `SIGTERM` signal? If yes what would be the side effect of this call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a sig-handler of type SA_SIGINFO.
Then you will get the siginfo_t which contains si_pid which is signalling process.
http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction

Comment: sample please? hopefully something that's compatible with MacOS ?

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @rib's answer:

Current versions of strace display that info

```
read(0, 0x7f4ab8353000, 4096)           = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=1, si_uid=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGTERM +++
```

I can see that my process was killed by pid #1  (init, i.e. upstart)

p.s. My CentOS (6.0 & 6.4) did not have it so I built it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/, not sure what version added it